# tilde display within url

Tags: urls, cv

I am using the [Two Column CV class from ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/two-column-cv). My academic website includes a tilde, but the tilde character is not displayed (although the hyperlink is correct). It is important for my resume to be readable when printed, so I cannot ignore the missing tilde. How do I fix this?

```
\personal[www.institution.edu/~username/]
```

displays as `www.institution.edu/ username/` when printed (note the space where the tilde should appear).

Comment: maybe `\~` or `\ttfamily\char126` or `$\sim$`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - Changing the URL string in this way will probably render it unusable for hyperlinking, right?

Comment: @Mico I will take your word on it, as I am not a hyperlinking type person.  I will therefore also upvote your accepted answer! :^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you do the following:

- At the very top of your tex file, *before* `\documentclass...`, insert the following two lines:

  ```
  \RequirePackage{url}
  \urlstyle{same}
  ```
- In the left-hand column of the main ShareLaTeX window, click on the tag for `tccv.cls`. Scroll down to the definition of the `\personal` macro. (It should start at around line 108.) By default, the penultimate line of the macro's definition should look like this:

  ```
  \ifstrempty{#1}{}{\smallskip\\ \Lightning & \href{http://#1}{#1}}
  ```
- Change this line to

  ```
  \ifstrempty{#1}{}{\smallskip\\ \Lightning & \url{#1}}
  ```

  If there's a chance you'll be using a pdf viewer that doesn't handle "plain" URL strings well, you should probably write:

  ```
  \ifstrempty{#1}{}{\smallskip\\ \Lightning & \href{http://#1}{\url{#1}}}
  ```

  i.e., encase the second instance of `#1` in a `\url{...}` wrapper.
- Go back to your main tex file and click on "Recompile".